# How do I get the raw predictions (-r) from Vowpal Wabbit when running in daemon mode?

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

Using the below, I'm able to get both the raw predictions and the final predictions as a file:

```
cat train.vw.txt | vw -c -k --passes 30 --ngram 5 -b 28 --l1 0.00000001 --l2 0.0000001 --loss_function=logistic -f model.vw --compressed --oaa 3

cat test.vw.txt | vw -t -i model.vw --link=logistic -r raw.txt -p predictions.txt
```

However, I'm unable to get the raw predictions when I run VW as a daemon:

```
vw -t -i model.vw --daemon --port 26542 --link=logistic
```

Do I have a pass in a specific argument or parameter to get the raw predictions? I prefer the raw predictions, not the final predictions. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On systems supporting `/dev/stdout` (and `/dev/stderr`), you may try this:

```
vw -t -i model.vw --daemon --port 26542 --link=logistic -r /dev/stdout
```

The daemon will write raw predictions into standard output which in this case end up in the same place as localhost port 26542.

The relative order of lines is guaranteed because the code dealing with different prints within each example (e.g non-raw vs raw) is always serial.

Comment: thanks for the solution. Unfortunately the daemon writes the raw predictions in the stdout of it's own process, whereas the function requesting output lives in a separate process. So in practice, the calling function has to send the data to the daemon, get the response, then make a second request to get the raw predictions. Having to make two requests is killing us in terms of latency (this is blocking). Is there any way to send the raw predictions in the output directly to the calling process, instead of just the sending the class (which in fact we don't want)?

Comment: as an aside, we extracted the hash table from the VW model, matched the output from the sigmoid function, and attempted to replace the daemon with a direct dictionary lookup. In practice, the lookups are expensive when you have 10M keys...

Comment: Depends on the implementation.  `vw` is very efficient C++.  It predicts as fast as it does IO (the learning thread is almost always slower than the parsing/hashing/atof thread), so when an interpreted language like python or java is involved, that other process, rather than vw would be your bottleneck.  As for dual-process interaction: you may be running single-line buffered. For best performance, you should make the bufffer as big as possible, and delay interaction. A double context switch every line is a sure way performance killer.  I've seen 20x speedups just by avoiding context switches.

Comment: Agreed on the double context switch, but I need every line scored since there is a subsequent action that is based on the scoring, so batching them in a buffer won't work...

Comment: -r /dev/stdout is piping the raw output to stdout. Is there any way to route that to another port?

Comment: Not in the current `vw` code, unfortunately; but patches are always welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Since [November 2015](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/pull/837), the easiest way how to obtain probabilities is to use `--oaa=N --loss_function=logistic --probabilities -p probs.txt`. (Or if you need label-dependent features: `--csoaa_ldf=mc --loss_function=logistic --probabilities -p probs.txt`.)

`--probabilities` work with `--daemon` as well. There should be no more need for using `--raw_predictions`.

Answer (score 2):

`--raw_predictions` is a kind of hack (the semantic depends on the reductions used) and it is not supported in `--daemon` mode. (Something like `--output_probabilities` would be useful and not difficult to implement and it would work in daemon mode, but so far no one had time to implement it.)

As a workaround, you can run VW in a pipe, so it reads stdin and writes the probabilities to stdout:

`cat test.data | vw -t -i model.vw --link=logistic -r /dev/stdout | script.sh`

Comment: this doesn't work in production, since the input data is a stream, so the model has to run as a daemon

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/issues/1118 you can try adding `--scores` option in command line: 
`vw --scores -t -i model.vw --daemon --port 26542`

It helped me with my oaa model.